# How can I pause animated GIFs in Messages.app on OS X?

Tags: macos, applications, messages, animation

I have a group message where my friends and I enjoy sharing animated GIFs. Sometimes, when one of these stays on screen for a long time, it will eat my CPU and cause my fan to spin up/make noise.

I enjoy the GIFs, but in order to keep my fan quiet, I often delete them, which reduces the CPU usage. **I have a hunch that if I could pause the animation, it wouldn't use as much processor power. Is there any way I can do this?**

*I'm currently on OS X Yosemite (10.10.3) and using Messages 8.0 (4752)*

*Edit by Tetsujin Aug '17*
The bounty I'm offering isn't for the same reason as the OP, i.e. CPU, but merely the irritation factor of watching them go round & round & round ... & round...

Comment: Do GIF's really take up that much CPU? A GIF is just a bunch of frames and should be of no harm to the CPU.

Comment: I thought I'd throw a bounty at this rather than set up a dupe. For me, it's purely the irritation factor - I've probably seen Snoopy hug Charlie Brown a thousand times out of the corner of my eye this morning. The only reason it's not in the bin yet is just in case there's a pause button somewhere ;)

Answer (score 1):

**You can not pause an animated GIF.**

But build-in in your operating system is the power of **App Nap** which is developed just for your needs. Shamelessly copied from the ['Power Efficiency in OSX'](https://www.apple.com/media/us/osx/2013/docs/OSX_Power_Efficiency_Technology_Overview.pdf) PDF from apple.com. It is an easy read.

> **App Nap**
>
> While your Mac can run many different apps at the same time, the
>   reality is that you’re typically interacting with only one of them,
>   and in some cases (such as using a full-screen app), you can’t even
>   see what the other apps are doing. App Nap takes advantage of this
>   fact by putting applications that you can’t see into a special low-
>   power state that regulates their CPU usage as well as network and disk
>   I/O. App Nap can be automatically triggered in the following
>   situations:
>
> • The app’s windows are not visible.
>
> • The app is not playing audio.
>
> • The developer has not explicitly made the app exempt from App Nap by using the existing IOKit IOPMAssertion API (currently used in OS X to prevent the system from sleeping while an app is busy).
>
> • An app is in background and hasn’t drawn recently.

Btw: GIF is pronounced as pronounced as ɡɪf or dʒɪf ;)

Comment: Not really a fix - if the app's window is not visible, it's not irritating ;-) Netscape used to be able to play gifs once through, then stop.

Comment: Ha ha, that was what I thought as well, but the OP even enjoys the GIFs, he justs wants less CPU usage ;), Safari also has such a plugin: https://sixcolors.com/post/2016/03/stop-safari-from-animating-gifs/